# Why can't I map different alpha values for different bars in `ggplot2::geom_col(aes(alpha = ...))`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a bar plot in which one bar stands out more saliently than others. To this end, my strategy is to tweak the `alpha` value of the bars. However, I end up with a strange output in which the transparency looks the same, regardless of the `alpha` values I map.

### Example

Let's use `mtcars` and select 5 rows of it. In the data, I create a utility column named `my_alpha`, which gets value of `1` for the bar I wish to highlight in the plot, and other decimal value (say, `0.5`) for the other bars. The data from `my_alpha` will be passed as the `alpha` values in the barplot.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

my_mtcars <- 
  tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, "cars") %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%
  mutate(my_alpha = ifelse(cars == "Datsun 710", 1, 0.5))

my_mtcars
#>                cars  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb my_alpha
#> 1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      0.5
#> 2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      0.5
#> 3        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1      1.0
#> 4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1      0.5
#> 5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2      0.5

p_0.5 <- 
  ggplot(my_mtcars, aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha = my_alpha))

p_0.5
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

### The problem

Although the plot above seems fine, the problem is revealed when we tweak the values in `my_alpha`. If I had chosen `0.9` instead of `0.5`, I would have expected much less transparency in the plot. However, the following plot looks exactly the same as the one above.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

my_mtcars <- 
  tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, "cars") %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%
  mutate(my_alpha = ifelse(cars == "Datsun 710", 1, 0.9))

p_0.9 <- 
  ggplot(my_mtcars, aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha = my_alpha))

p_0.9
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

**The question:**

How come `p_0.5` and `p_0.9` look the same, despite the difference in the values that are passed from `my_mtcars["my_alpha"]` to `geom_col(aes(alpha = my_alpha))`?

Comment: Try adding `scale_alpha_identity()`. The reason your alpha doesn't work as expected, is that because the alpha is a *mapped* aesthetic (inside the `aes()` function), it gets rescaled to a value between `c(0.1, 1)` (default range of `scale_alpha_continuous()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your alpha doesn't work as expected is because the alpha is a *mapped* aesthetic: you declared it inside the `aes()` function. As a mapped aesthetic, it gets a scale that rescales the provided value from the data range to a rescaled range (`c(0.1, 1)` for default `scale_alpha_continuous()`).

There are several ways around this.

1. You can set alpha outside the `aes()` function.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

my_mtcars <- 
  tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, "cars") %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%
  mutate(my_alpha = ifelse(cars == "Datsun 710", 1, 0.3))

ggplot(my_mtcars, aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) +
  geom_col(alpha = my_mtcars$my_alpha)
```

[image]

2. You can wrap alpha in `I()` to automatically assign the identity scale.

```r
ggplot(my_mtcars, aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha = I(my_alpha)))
```

3. You can manually assign the identity scale.

```r
ggplot(my_mtcars, aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha = my_alpha)) +
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

4. If you want the alpha legend, you have two options. You can set `scale_alpha_identity(guide = guide_legend())` or set the limits and range of the continuous scale:

```r
ggplot(my_mtcars, aes(x = cars, y = mpg, fill = cars)) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha = my_alpha)) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), range = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>